# Increase speed of slow sql-code

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm  trying to increase the speed of the sql code below. Load time right now is around 0.662 sec. The problem is that i need to loop this code for each day of the selected month and then 31*0.662 sec ~30sec is way to long time for loading.

```
select fname,lname,(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r.edate,r.sdate))-r.break) as TotalDiff from tbluser u LEFT JOIN
 tblregtime r
 on (r.userid = u.id and
    r.projectid = 21 
     and sdate='2013-11-27'
    )


    INNER JOIN tblgroup_users gU ON gU.userID = u.id 
    INNER JOIN tblgroup_brukare gB on gB.tblGroupID=gU.tblGroupID where (gB.tblprojectID = 21 AND (gU.status=0 OR gU.status=2))

    order by u.fname ASC,u.lname ASC
```

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN <your statement>` and where did you set index?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looping SQL-calls is a bad thing. You should make just one call that returns resultset for all desired days and then parse the results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running your sql query 31 times for each day, you could try running a single query for all days and handle them appropriately in your code (php or whatever).

Here's a suggested alternate of your query which will run only one time (you may need to rephrase it a bit). Can you try it and let us know how long that takes? Also, to further optimize, it will be helpful to post your query plan, and maybe create an sql fiddle.

```
select fname,lname,(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r.edate,r.sdate))-r.break) as TotalDiff, sdate
from tbluser u
LEFT JOIN tblregtime r on (r.userid = u.id and r.projectid = 21 and sdate between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31')

INNER JOIN tblgroup_users gU ON gU.userID = u.id 
INNER JOIN tblgroup_brukare gB on gB.tblGroupID=gU.tblGroupID where (gB.tblprojectID = 21 AND (gU.status=0 OR gU.status=2))

order by sdate ASC, u.fname ASC,u.lname ASC
```

Comment: Is there any reason for this section "r.projectid = 21 and sdate between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31'" to be included in the ON section?  I would have though that would be a WHERE condition at the end.  Also if the project id is being checked in two tables, maybe that should be one of the join conditions between the two...

Comment: @AldenW. I agree and I don't see the point. But I just rephrased the OP's question. It would certainly make more sense if it was in the `where` clause or the `left join` was actually an `inner join`

Comment: @AldenW.Yes for getting a zero value for the user even if there is no record in tblregtime table!